# If $x^2+ax+b+1=0$ ($a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$) has integral roots, prove that $a^2+b^2$ is composite.

Tags: number-theory

> If $x^2+ax+b+1=0$ ($a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$) has integral roots, prove that
>   $a^2+b^2$ is composite.

Would someone please help me to solve the above question? I'm not able to understand how I should proceed.
Take $b\ne-1$.

Comment: What is $b=/=1$ ?

Comment: I meant not equal to -1. I don't know how to type that symbol.

Comment: Compute the discriminant.

Comment: Let
$$x^2+ax+b+1=(x-r)(x-s)$$
so that $r,s$ are the two roots, then try to compute $a^2+b^2$ in terms of $r,s$.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Vieta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)
$$x_1 + x_2 = -a$$
$$x_1 \cdot x_2 = b+1$$
or
$$a^2+b^2=\left(x_1+x_2\right)^2+\left(x_1\cdot x_2-1\right)^2=\\
x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_1x_2+x_1^2x_2^2-2x_1x_2+1=\\
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1^2x_2^2+1=\\
\left(x_1^2+1\right)\left(x_2^2+1\right)$$
Since $b\ne-1$, then none of $x_1,x_2$ is $0$ and the result follows.