# If If $x^2+ax+b+1=0$ has roots which are positive integers, then $(a^2+b^2)$ can be which of the given choices?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, roots, quadratics

> If $x^2+ax+b+1=0$ has roots which are **positive integers**, then $(a^2+b^2)$ can be
>
> (A) 50
> (B) 37
> (C) 19
> (D) 61

My approach: I first took roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ and then applied sum and product of roots according to Vieta's formula. But I don't think we can get any value with that. Any help will be much appreciation.

Also can we actually find the range of $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Try to find $a$ and $b$ from the answer choices. For instance, there are no $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 19$.

Comment: Worth noting:  all those options are quite small, so there are only a few cases you need to check.

Comment: If $m,n$ are the roots show that $a^2+b^2=\left(m^2+1\right)\left(n^2+1\right)$

Comment: You can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3073025/if-x2axb1-0-a-b-in-mathbbz-has-integral-roots-prove-that-a2b2/3073062#3073062) property and exclude all the primes from the list (exactly 3 options out of 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this equation is having positive integer roots so the sum as well as product of the roots should be positive integer. 
$\alpha + \beta = -a \gt 0$ and $\alpha \beta = b+1 \gt 0$.
Which gives us the two conditions:
$$a \lt 0$$ and $$b \gt -1$$
Now since the equation is having positive integers as roots so sum of roots is a positive integer implying $a$ is an integer and the product is also an integer implying $b$ is also an integer.

Now for the equation $a^2+b^2$ we can only have choices where $a$ is a negative integer and $b$ is an integer greater than $-1$.

For the first choice $a^2+b^2=50$ you will get the values of $(a,b)$ as  $(-1,7)$$(-5,5)$ and $(-7,1)$ out of which only $(-5,5)$ satisfies.

For the second choice $a^2+b^2=37$, you get the values of $(a,b)$ as $(-1,6)$ and $(-6,1)$ but none of them will satisfy since the discriminant is not a perfect square.

For the third choice there is no such $(a,b)$ and for the fourth option the values of $(a,b)$ are $(-5,6)$ and $(-6,5)$ and none of them actually have a perfect square discriminant.

So option A is correct. Hope this helps ….

Answer (score 2):

We need that $a$ and $b$ will be naturals and there is a natural $n$ for which $$a^2-4(b+1)=n^2.$$
Thus, $$a^2+b^2=n^2+b^2+4b+4=n^2+(b+2)^2.$$
Can you end it now?